# Is it safe to connect CR2032 cells in parallel?

Tags: batteries, parallel, coin-cell

As mentioned in the title, I would like to connect two CR2032 cells in parallel to increase their capacity. If they are slightly different voltages then won't the better battery "charge" the  weaker battery until the voltages equalize? My batteries are non-rechargeable. Is this dangerous? Should I prevent current flow with diodes? They will drop 0.7 volts, which is a nuisance.

Comment: Have you measured the current when they are connected in parallel?

Comment: What's the context? Is this a one-off, and you happen to have a couple of batteries? Are you designing a hobby project? Are you designing a professional product?

Comment: `[diodes] will drop 0.7 V` Si PN near nominal current&temperature, yes. Something to be powered by two CR2032 should draw about .5 mA.

Comment: Note (as mentioned in danmcb's answer): The voltage dropped by a [Schottky barrier diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_diode) is significantly less than the voltage dropped by a classic silicon diode. _Enough_ less? That's for you to decide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a good idea unless you use some sort of device to ensure that current cannot flow back INTO the battery terminal, which in extreme cases can lead to overheating and explosion (admittedly unlikely at these energy levels.) The problem is that if one of the batteries is flat and the other new, their terminal voltages will be very different, or even perhaps if they are of different brands. [See here for more on this.](https://batteryguy.com/kb/knowledge-base/connecting-batteries-in-parallel/)

A first order solution to protect against this is a diode, but then you lose some voltage (about 0.2V for Schottky) to the diode forward voltage. [There are also MOSFET based circuits which function as an ideal diode](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slvaea8a/slvaea8a.pdf) (though they might be more for selecting one of N supplies than current sharing, you need to think this through a bit).

Comment: Since this is a good answer, I'll add a comment here. If the voltages differs just slightly (and I don't have any numbers here) it's ok to parallel them. You should however consider the gain of doing this, instead of getting a battery with higher capacity like the CR2450.

Comment: Indeed, but you should also consider the possibility that the next user will likely be unaware of the issue in your design. Context is everything here.

Comment: If the circuit isn't for the broader audience and the batteries are approximately of same voltage, well, but it's all my point of view.